# How does lspci find out physical slot number of a PCI(E) device?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

`lspci` is capable to show physical slot number in the verbose presentation:

[image]

I'd like to find out how it does it. I am going to apply this method in the driver that I would like to modify, so it would enumerate the devices (with the same ID) and disambiguate the device files according to physical slot. Like /dev/device_*physslot* . The driver will run on Ubuntu 18

I tried to dig in the source code. I found the relevant line 775 in https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/master/lspci.c:

```
if (p->phy_slot)
    printf("\tPhysical Slot: %s\n", p->phy_slot);
```

p is `struct pci_dev`. That had been quite confusing because standard `linux/pci.h` does not have field `phy_slot` until I figured out that is [their own (re)definition](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/master/lib/pci.h)

The structure [is filled](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/master/lib/access.c) by  the function

```
int
pci_fill_info_v38(struct pci_dev *d, int flags)
{
  unsigned int uflags = flags;
  if (uflags & PCI_FILL_RESCAN)
    {
      uflags &= ~PCI_FILL_RESCAN;
      pci_reset_properties(d);
    }
  if (uflags & ~d->known_fields)
    d->methods->fill_info(d, uflags);
  return d->known_fields;
}
```

`fill_info` is  a function pointer defined in https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/master/lib/internal.h (line 44)

And that's where I lost track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper in the source and succeeding to run lspci in the debugger (thanks to Netbeans) I found out that lspci uses sysfs to gather information.
In particular /sys/bus/pci/slots/*slot_num*/address file contains the bus address of the slot. And that's what lspci uses to attribute slots to bus addresses in the function `sysfs_fill_slots` (in sysfs.c)

Unfortunately this method turns out to be unsuitable for my purposes, since it is not possible to perform file I/O from kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

If you run dmidecode it will show the stored platform information, which will tell you the mapping of physical slots to PCIe address.  For example:

```
Handle 0x001D, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 1                      <== SLOT (starting at 0)
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.3    <== PCI BUS ADDRESS
```

Proogrammatic list of slots:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 9 |awk '/ID:/ {id=$2} /Bus Address/ {print "Slot",id+1,"PCIe",$3}'
Slot 1 PCIe 0000:00:01.0
Slot 2 PCIe 0000:00:1c.3
Slot 3 PCIe 0000:00:1c.4
Slot 4 PCIe 0000:00:1c.5
Slot 5 PCIe 0000:00:1c.6
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant programatically, with C code

Comment: Just read and parse the DMI data, then.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I ask for. I extended the explanation of application, so you perhaps would be able to provide suitable answer