# How to find out physical slot number of a PCI(E) device with system calls?

Tags: linux-kernel, pci

I'd like to find a way to figure out physical slot of a PCI-E device from the bus address. I would like to use to modify a driver/kernel module, so it would enumerate the devices (with the same ID) and disambiguate the device files according to physical slot. Like /dev/device_*physslot* . The driver will run on Ubuntu 18

`lspci` is capable to show physical slot number in the verbose presentation
[image]

However, as [I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71356514/2466685), it accomplishes it over sysfs, which cannot be accessed from kernel module.

So I need to do it somehow with system calls.
Or perhaps it is possible to figure out, where sysfs gets /sys/bus/pci/slots/slot_num/address property?

Comment: "it accomplishes it over sysfs, which cannot be accessed from kernel module." - A kernel module **can** access files, including the ones under sysfs.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Not really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275386/file-i-o-in-a-linux-kernel-module

Also trying to replicate `lspci`'s  method would also reqire to traverse sysfs directory structure (to discover enumerated physical slots), which is highly unlikely  to be possible in kernel mode.

Comment: The kernel reads the DMI informstion.

Comment: @AndreyPro: [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275386/file-i-o-in-a-linux-kernel-module) referenced by you doesn't tell that accessing files from the kernel is impossible, it just tells that this is generally a bad idea. As for iterating directory, it is also **possible** from the kernel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617244/how-to-read-contents-of-a-directory-recursively-in-linux-kernel.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I looked into your suggestion and I can't understand how to use `dir_context` and `iterate_dir` to get the information about directory.

Comment: Usually, a udev rule is used to create symlinks to a kernel device name, with a more meaningful name. Udev rules cannot see the PCI physical slot number directly, but rules can run programs to do tricky stuff such as figuring out the physical slot number.

Comment: Is it too hard to read the source code? (Check _drivers/pci/slot.c_)